# Unable to migrate schema to remote AWS RDS Postgres DB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've created a AWS RDS Postgres DB and want to use it in my Rails 6 app. I'm able to create a db via `rails db:create:local` but `rails db:migrate:local` while not throwing errors, does not actually create tables from the migration files.

My `database.yml` file:

```
default: &default 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: tml-portal-app 
  username:  <%= Rails.application.credentials[:tml_portal_username] %>
  password:  <%= Rails.application.credentials[:tml_portal_password] %>
  host:  <%= Rails.application.credentials[:tml_portal_host] %>
  port: 5432
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>



development:
  aws:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: requests
    username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_username] %>
    password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_password] %>
    host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_host] %>
    cast: false 
    port: 3306
  local:
    <<: *default


production:
  aws:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: requests
    username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_username] %>
    password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_password] %>
    host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_host] %>
    cast: false 
    port: 3306
  local:
    <<: *default


test: 
  aws:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: requests
    username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_username] %>
    password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_password] %>
    host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_host] %>
    cast: false 
    port: 3306
  local:
    <<: *default
```

You'll notice that I'm also using a remote AWS RDS MySqL db which was created by someone else. This connection is fine but I did not have to do any migrations for it. Is there a step I'm missing regarding migrating tables to a newly created remote db?